# Insert existing users with temporary password into .NET identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 application with .NET Identity 2.0. I need to migrate users from the clients legacy database. I am going to use an INSERT statement to insert them into the SQL Server tables (ASPNetUsers, ASPNetUserROles etc).

The problem is I want to insert a temporary password (firstname+lastname). Then I will separately send them an email and ask them to log in and change the password on the first log in.

How do I insert a hashed password (based on firstname+lastname) through a SQL Insert statement into the table?

Thanks,

Sanjeev

Comment: You will need to use the methods of the [UserManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class to add you user and temporary password.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote the following code. It seems to work. The first part uses the UserManager methods and the second part inserts the person into my own db tables.

Please comment if this is the right approach!

```
    public ActionResult Seed()
    {
        string lastname;
        string firstname;
        string email;
        string password;

        lastname = "LastNAme";
        firstname = "FirstName";
        email = "Email@gmail.com";
        password = "TempPassword";

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
        var result = UserManager.Create(user, password);
        UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
        var person = new Person()
        {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            UserId = user.Id,
            LastName = lastname,
            FirstName = firstname,
            Email = email
        };
        db.People.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

}